# How is memory occupied in this piece of code?

Tags: c

I am new to C and I am trying to understand how the memory allocation is being done by the compiler. Here is a piece of code that I wrote to understand what is happening:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int x=10;
    char y='A';
    printf("x: %p \ny: %p\n", &x, &y);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x: 0x7fffcc33e10c
y: 0x7fffcc33e10b
```

Int occupies 4bytes and Char occupies 1byte. So how is it that the locations where these variables are stored are consecutive? I am not able to understand this.

## Edit:

As @Rup suggested in the comments below, I tried adding more integers to the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int x=10;
    int m = 11;
    int n = 11;
    int o = 11;
    char y='A';
    printf("x: %p \nm: %p\nn: %p\no: %p\ny: %p\n", &x, &m, &n, &o, &y);
    return 0;
}
```

I got the following output:

```
x: 0x7fff825c2e68
m: 0x7fff825c2e6c
n: 0x7fff825c2e70
o: 0x7fff825c2e74
y: 0x7fff825c2e67
```

the space for y is allocated as 1byte and the x,m,n,o integers are allocated 4bytes.
Thank you for all your responses.

Comment: Why not try adding a few more variables to see what happens, e.g. another `int z` afterwards?? I'd guess they're consecutive because that's the space for y, 10b, and x is stored in four bytes 10c-f. But this can also depend on your ABI's alignment rules so might look non-obvious

Comment: Shall we ignore the undefined behavior of not providing three valid arguments to `printf` for the given format string that clearly calls for them ?

Comment: The code you show exhibits *undefined behavior*, since you have three `"%p"` format specifiers but only two arguments. Also note that the argument type for `"%p"` is specified to be `void *`, you really need a cast to be fully correct.

Comment: I think you missed that `y` is actually stored *before* `x`. This is fine. `y` is your 1-byte char at `...10b` and your int starts at `...10c`, which is the next byte.

Comment: Try to add a third variable and printf its pointer. :)

Comment: "how memory allocation is done by the compiler"? So that each object has a constant address during its lifetime as given by `&`, and that distinct objects do not overlap. That's it.

Comment: I think that modern compiler might establish where to allocate variable in a different order from what the source code specifies. Different case is if you analyze variable position and dimension inside a data structure.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but this UB  is not relevant. It is the UB on the machines where different types of pointers have different internal representation. If OP uses old CRAY machine the code would be invalid. But it is rather very unusual

Comment: Sorry, I forgot I had additional `%p` in there. I didn't notice.

Comment: @Rup thank you, adding more variables at the end answered my question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How memory for variables is allocated is entirely a function of the implementation - the answer will vary from platform to platform.  Variables don't have to be laid out in the order they were declared, and depending on alignment requirements, there may be "holes" (unused bytes) between the end of one variable and the beginning of another.

Here's what's likely happening on your system (all byte values in hex format):

```
   +----+
y: | 41 | 0x7fffcc33e10b    
   +----+
x: | 0a | 0x7fffcc33e10c    // assuming little-endian representation
   +----+
   | 00 | 0x7fffcc33e10d
   +----+
   | 00 | 0x7fffcc33e10e
   +----+
   | 00 | 0x7fffcc33e10f
   +----+
```

On x86 and similar platforms, the stack grows "downward" towards decreasing addresses (x86 is also little-endian, so the addressed byte is the least significant byte of a multi-byte object).  So `x` is allocated "first" at address `0x7fffcc33e10c`, and then `y` is allocated at the next available object address.  Since `y` is a `char` and only a single byte wide, that next available address is `0x7fffcc33e10b`.  If `y` were also a 4-byte `int`, then the next available address would be `0x7fffcc33e108`, and the layout would be something like this:

```
   +----+
y: | 41 | 0x7fffcc33e108
   +----+
   | 00 | 0x7fffcc33e109
   +----+
   | 00 | 0x7fffcc33e10a
   +----+
   | 00 | 0x7fffcc33e10b
   +----+
x: | 0a | 0x7fffcc33e10c    
   +----+
   | 00 | 0x7fffcc33e10d
   +----+
   | 00 | 0x7fffcc33e10e
   +----+
   | 00 | 0x7fffcc33e10f
   +----+
```

**EDIT**

An interesting exercise would be to declare

```
int x = 10;
char y = 'A';
int z = 20;
```

and see how they're laid out.  If they were laid out in the order declared, then you will likely see one or more unused bytes between `y` and `z`, since most platforms require multi-byte objects to start at an even address.  I wouldn't be surprised if a compiler decided to lay them out as `x`, `z`, `y`, since that would minimize any such "holes".

**EDIT OF THE EDIT**

Tried it myself, got the following result:

```
       Item         Address   00   01   02   03
       ----         -------   --   --   --   --
          x  0x7ffee73b8a78   0a   00   00   00    ....

          y  0x7ffee73b8a77   41   0a   00   00    A...

          z  0x7ffee73b8a70   14   00   00   00    ....
```

Three unused bytes between `y` and `z`, so 4-byte objects clearly must be aligned to addresses that are multiples of 4.  Graphically, we have

```
    +----+
z : | 14 | 0x7ffee73b8a70
    +----+ 
    | 00 | 0x7ffee73b8a71
    +----+
    | 00 | 0x7ffee73b8a72
    +----+
    | 00 | 0x7ffee73b8a73
    +----+
    | ?? | 0x7ffee73b8a74
    +----+
    | ?? | 0x7ffee73b8a75
    +----+
    | ?? | 0x7ffee73b8a76
    +----+
 y: | 41 | 0x7ffee73b8a77
    +----+
 x: | 0a | 0x7ffee73b8a78
    +----+
    | 00 | 0x7ffee73b8a79
    +----+
    | 00 | 0x7ffee73b8a7a
    +----+
    | 00 | 0x7ffee73b8a7b
    +----+
```

Answer (score 3):

#### My answer is not accurate nor complete, so for a better explanation refer to [John Bode's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56838260/4935567).

I added two extra variables:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int x=10;
    char y='A';
    int z = 3;
    char m = 'a';
    printf("x: %p \ny: %p\nz: %p\nm: %p\n", &x, &y, &z, &m);
    return 0;
}
```

and here's the output:

```
x: 0x7ffd2e8e0630 
y: 0x7ffd2e8e062e
z: 0x7ffd2e8e0634
m: 0x7ffd2e8e062f
```

So I guess the compiler first allocate `char`s and then `int`s.

Comment: I think it was better to share some comments on why my answer is wrong and why being down-voted!

Comment: I think that modern compiler might establish where to allocate variable in a different order from what the source code specifies. Different case is if you analyze variable position and dimension inside a data structure.

Comment: I think it's a perfectly good answer because it answers the OP's question in a way that demonstrates the point: how local variables get ordered in the stack is undefined and entirely at the whim of your specific compiler. In this case your compiler does seem to be exhibiting some pattern but there's no guarantee that a different compiler (or even the same compiler with different flags or in a different context) will do the same. Either way it shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: Yes, this answer definitely helped me understand why I thought that initial variables in my question were consecutive. It just happens that my compiler allocated space for `char` and then allocated 'int` later just as in your case. But yes as @Iguananaut says your compiler is exhibiting a different pattern than mine. I used `gcc` compiler.